# Reporting Services: alternate row background when filtering rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, alternate

I have a dataset with 10 fields. I group that dataset into 3 groups, where each group is a child of previous one. So it would be something like:

```
Users
    Username
        LoginDate
```

The problem is that not all login dates have to be shown, so I have a field in the dataset which determines whether that row should be visible or not. But when I filter rows, my alternate rows coloring breaks. Anybody have an idea how to fix it?

For coloring rows I use this:

```vbscript
=IIf(RunningValue(Fields!Users.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) MOD 2, 
    "White", 
    "#C0C0C0")
```

Comment: I changed things a little bit. Instead of changing visibility, i added filter, so now data is filtered and should be treated normally, but it isn't. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Your code looks fine, I can't reproduce it with the info you provided. Can you add some more detail (what grouping are you filtering on? is it a matrix or a table? what is the filter expression? etc), or perhaps even a small basic test-setup to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to bring the rows upto Report, add the where clause in the dataset query and filter that out and then the Colouring will be normal